# Tell Jackson to ignore property only when generating an xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Is there a way to tell Jackson to only ignore a property if it generates XML with annotations?

I have a JPA entity which is exposed via REST (Spring Boot). I'd like to tell Jackson to ignore e.g. the property street when generating XML but not when generating a JSON String

```
@Entity
public class anObject{

  String name;

  @JsonIgnore //only when converting to XML? Still need it on a JSON String
  String street

//Various Getters, Setters, etc.
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I presume you have different `ObjectMapper` for XML and JSON. You can set a mixin annotation only for the XML mapper. E.g.

the mixin annotation :

```
abstract class anObjectMixIn {
  @JsonIgnore String street;
}
```

the mapper code :

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.addMixIn(anObject.class, anObjectMixIn.class);
```

And delete the `@JsonIgnore` over `String street`. Note how the mixin is only applied on `xmlMapper`

Comment: I see that would definitely work and thank you for that suggestion but I'm looking for a method were i don't have to use a different mapper than the one that Springboot uses per default. I may have to use this option at some point nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson allows you tu use JAXB annotations, have a look at the [JAXB module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations).

You can use both Jackson and JAXB together but you can tell which one has priority over the other as mentioned in [the documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations), so you can keep your core Jackson annotations for JSON and specialize with JAXB annotations for your XML serialisation.

```
AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(primaryIntrospector, secondaryIntropsector);
```

Comment: I stumbled upon `@XmlTransient` and I think this ties into your answer. It may work but I have to check at some point.